# MATLAB: Remove specific elements from array

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, if-statement, cell

**Question 1:** I have a 1x15 array, comprising of positive integers and negative integers. I wish to implement a MATLAB code which keeps all positive integers and skips the cells with negative contents.

I have tried the following:

```
X = [1 2 3 4 5 -10 1 -5 4 6 8 9 2 4 -2];
[r c] = size(X);
for i=1:r
    for j=1:c
        if X(i,j)<0
            X(i,j)=X(i,j+1)
        end
    end
end
```

The output should be:

```
X_new = [1 2 3 4 5 1 4 6 8 9 2 4]
```

How do I do this?

---

**Question 2:**

```
X = [1 2 3 4 5 -10 1 -5 4 6 8 9 2 4 -2]
Y = [5 3 8 9 4  5 6  7 4 7 9 5 2 1  4]
```

From Question 1,

```
X_new = [1 2 3 4 5 1 4 6 8 9 2 4]
```

I need to delete the corresponding values in `Y` so that:

```
Y_new = [5 3 8 9 4 6 4 7 9 5 2 1]
```

How do I perform this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MATLAB, manipulating arrays and matrices can be done much easier than for-loop solutions,
in your task, can do find and delete negative value in the array, simply, as follows:

```
Idx_neg = X < 0;  % finding X indices corresponding to negative elements
X ( Idx_neg   ) = [];  % removing elements using [] operator

Y ( Idx_neg  ) = [];   % removing corresponding elements in Y array
```

Comment: The Y(X<0) = []; does not function. It does not give me the desired array.